# Reference HTML Elements by name (with square brackets in them) via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hey everyone, I am trying to hide/show different html elements (div, etc...) based on whether a checkbox is checked or if a specific value is chosen from a dropdown box. I was wondering if someone can help me out. The html element is defined along the lines of this (below), and i'm not sure how to reference it by name with brackets in it. The page i'm using has jquery enabled, and i'd like to use it if possible. Thanks!

```
<input type="checkbox" name="addons[2]" />
```

Also - I cannot modify the checkbox's code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help, here is the final code I used

```
$("input[name='customfield[4]']").click(

    function()
    {
        if ($("input[name='customfield[4]']").is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#addons").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#addons").show();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: You can use $(this).is(":checked") in your JS code. Also, there is a way to do this purely in CSS using the :checked pseudo-element - #addons {display: none}  input[name=customefield\[4\]]:checked + #addons { display: block}. This assumes that the #addons div is next to this input element. Otherwise you can use ~ in place of +.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery to check if element is checked:

```
$("input[name='addons[2]']").attr("checked")
```

jQuery to loop over such elements that are checked:

```
$("input[name^='addons']:checked").each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an *inline* non-jQuery solution that bypasses the need to reference the square brackets entirely by using the javascript `this` keyword. Assuming you want to show/hide a `<div>` with `id="mydiv"`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="addons[2]" onclick="document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = (this.checked ? 'block' : 'none');" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great example - but unfortunately I can't modify the checkbox's code, it's autogenerated. I gave you a +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

avoid using [] in naming html elements