# Change attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in JS. I have this code:

```
<input type="text" name="address[company_name]" class="form-control " id="address[company_name]" value="" data-rule-required="false">
```

I have many inputs on my page. I need change only input with name address[company_name] => data-rule-required="true"

I try this, but it's not working:

```
$(".mybutton").click(function () {
  $('address[company_name]').prop(true);
});
```

How can I repair it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference HTML Elements by name (with square brackets in them) via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068503/reference-html-elements-by-name-with-square-brackets-in-them-via-javascript)

Comment: `$("[name='address[company_name]']").data("rule-required", true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to modify [data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes, here is a working snippet:

```js
$(".mybutton").click(function () {
    $('input[name="address[company_name]"]').data('rule-required', true);
    console.log($('input[name="address[company_name]"]').get(0));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="address[company_name]" class="form-control " id="address[company_name]" value="">
<button class="mybutton">Click</button>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: `$('address[company_name]')` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m, thanks for correcting me, I was typing fast, didn't notice my mistake! updated my answer.

Comment: The `.data()` API does **not** add attributes. It will *read* `data-` attribute values when present, but jQuery keeps an internal map for the API and will not update the actual attribute values in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

there you go.

```
$(".mybutton").click(function () {
    $('[name="address[company]"]').attr('data-rule-required', 'true');
});
```

Comment: This is what you'd do if for some reason you actually need to change the attribute value in the DOM.

Comment: @Pointy it entirely depends on what you use the data attribute for and *when*.  It's not enough to "change the attribute value in the DOM" if you've already read it using `.data("val")` as it won't affect a 2nd reading of `.data("val")`.  If using `.data()` at all, then you should always use `.data` and only `.data` and never `.attr("data-", "val")` - *but* if a third party incorrectly uses `.attr("data-")` to read the value, then yes, you have to - to cover an incorrect use.

Comment: Yes, personally I would not bother updating the actual attribute value as the `.data()` API works perfectly well.

Comment: You are all correct, if somehow you mess with the dom using jquery or vanilla js. .data() won't work.